# "list index out of range" Error in for loop

Tags: python, loops, indexing

Disclaimer: I'm not experienced with Sage/Python at all so this could be a really simple mistake

I have defined a list of lists called "weights"

```py
weights = [[0,24,16,4,1],[24,0,5,1,6],[16,5,0,15,7],[4,1,15,0,2],[1,6,7,2,0]]
```

that gives the cost, or weight of a certain path. So the first list would be starting from the 'zero'th node, next list is starting from the first node, etc.

And I want to create a function `getCost` that takes a list of integers from `0 to 4` and adds up all the costs that the path would total.

```py
def getCost(list):
    cost = weights[0][list[0]]
    for i in range(1,len(list)+1):
        if list[i] > 4 or list[i] < 0:
            print "Elements in list cannot be greater than 4."
            break
        else:
            cost += weights[list[i-1]][list[i]]
    return "The total cost of this path is " + cost

getCost([1,4,3,2])
```

But this gives me the following error message:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cocalc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smc_sagews/sage_server.py", line 1234, in execute
    flags=compile_flags), namespace, locals)
  File "", line 1, in <module>
  File "", line 4, in getCost
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What part of this makes the index out of range? I thought if I started the range of the for loop to start at `i=1`, I wouldn't run into a lower bound problem.

Comment: You go to `+1` which is out of range for `list[i]`

Comment: `list` is a reserved keyword in python, I would suggest you to use some other variable name

Comment: Also, you can simply use something like the following:
`for i in your_list` instead of `for i in range(1, len(list)+1)`.
At present, you assign the first element of your list to `cost`, which can violate the condition you specified, since there is no check.

Answer (score 1):

First of all and as @Swetank Podda said, `list` is a reserved keyword in python, so try to change `list` to another word like `ls` or `lst` (just a suggestion).

Then, you iterate up to `i=len(list)` that is out of range.

Remember that the last element of the list is at index `len(list)-1`:

```
lst=[1,2,3,4]
lst[len(lst)] 
>>> IndexError: list index out of range


lst=[1,2,3,4]
lst[len(lst)-1]
>>>4
```

So when you iterate in `range(1,len(list)+1)`, you will get index error, because:

```
#with for i in range(1,len(list)+1):
i=[1,2,3,...,len(list)]

#with for i in range(1,len(list)):
i=[1,2,3,...,len(list)-1]
```

Also at the return, cast the cost to string, because you cannot concatenate str and ints:

```
return "The total cost of this path is " + cost
>>>TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Try instead:

```
return "The total cost of this path is " + str(cost)
#or with fstrings
return f"The total cost of this path is {cost}"
```

So your code changed:

```
weights = [[0,24,16,4,1],[24,0,5,1,6],[16,5,0,15,7],[4,1,15,0,2],[1,6,7,2,0]]


def getCost(lst):
    cost = weights[0][lst[0]]
    for i in range(1,len(lst)):
        if lst[i] > 4 or lst[i] < 0:
            print("Elements in list cannot be greater than 4.")
            break
        else:
            cost += weights[lst[i-1]][lst[i]]
    return "The total cost of this path is " + str(cost)
```

Tests:

```
getCost([1,4,3,2])
>>>The total cost of this path is 47

getCost([1,4,3,7])
>>>Elements in list cannot be greater than 4.
>>>The total cost of this path is 32
```

Answer (score 1):

I will first explain the reason of error and then give the correct code below.

---

### Error Explanation

> `IndexError: list index out of range`

1. Index Error : You get this error when you are trying to access list index which is out of bounds. In you program, You are looping from 1 to `len(list)` inclusive in the following line -

   ```
   for i in range(1,len(list)+1):
   ```

   The indices are only till `len(list)-1` . Remember that `range(a,b)` will loop from `a` to `b-1`. So we want our loop to only execute for `1` to `len(list)-1`.

   For that, we have to change the looping to

   ```
   for i in range(1,len(list)):       # Will only loop from 1 to len(list)-1. So no IndexError would occur
   ```

   This would only loop till `len(list)-1` and you index won't go out of range of the list. This change would make your program work fine.
2. Concatenation Error : Another minor error in the program is on the line -

   ```
   return "The total cost of this path is " + cost
   ```

   This wouldn't work since we can't directly concatenate strings with int. So, we would have to convert cost into string using `str()` and then return after concatenating. You can also use a f-string if you are aware about it in python.

---

### Corrected Code -

```
weights = [[0,24,16,4,1],[24,0,5,1,6],[16,5,0,15,7],[4,1,15,0,2],[1,6,7,2,0]]

def getCost(lst):
    cost = weights[0][list[0][0]]
    for i in range(1,len(lst)):         # <-- Loop till range(1,len(list)) only so it doesn't go out of range
        if lst[i] > 4 or lst[i] < 0:
            print "Elements in list cannot be greater than 4."
            break
        else:
            cost += weights[lst[i-1]][lst[i]]
    return "The total cost of this path is " + str(cost)   # <- Note the change here... convert int to str and then concatenate

print(getCost([1,4,3,2]))
```

**Output :**

```
The total cost of this path is 47
```

---

#### Note :

Try not to use `list` as a variable name as it is a python *reserved keyword. I have changed list to lst in the code above*

Hope this helps !